# PHP behavior when calling specific function

Tags: php

I'm confused by a PHP behavior which I cannot explain:

Class that I'm using:

```
Class Photo extends DatabaseObject {
    public function photo(){
            return SITE_DOMAIN."/files/".$this->upload_dir."/".$this->photo;
    }
}
```

Call from html:

```
$i->photo();
```

PHP is giving me the following notice but otherwise I'm getting no errors:

```
Notice: Undefined property: Photo::$photo in C:\wamp\www\photo_gallery\includes\objects\photo.php on line 33
```

The funny part is, when i rename the function to `photo_path()`, I don't get that notice!!

the object variables are instantiated in the parent class(DatabaseObject):

public static function instantiate($record) {

```
    $class_name = get_called_class();
    $object = new $class_name;
    foreach ($record as $key => $value) {
            $object->$key = $value;
    }
    return $object;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show where `$this->photo` is being set as a member to `Photo`?

Comment: I use a function in the parent class to do that (i edited my question to reflect it)

Answer (score 0):

$this->photo points to a class variable (called property) which doesn't exist, try this:

```
Class Photo extends DatabaseObject {
    private $photo;
    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->photo = 'test.png';
    }
    public function photo(){
            return SITE_DOMAIN."/files/".$this->upload_dir."/".$this->photo;
    }
}
```

As for the funny part we need to have a look at your parent class you probably are overwritting a method or something.

Comment: Then why does php find that class variable when i rename the function:


public function photo_path(){
            return SITE_DOMAIN."/files/".$this->upload_dir."/".$this->photo;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Answer is already there in notice, as @Tom pointed out, read it carefully :

```
Notice: Undefined property: Photo::$photo in C:\wamp\www\photo_gallery\includes\objects\photo.php on line 33
```

Error message talks about an undefined property **Undefined property: Photo::$photo**, thus causing the error. It seems your call to $i->photo() is treated as a lambada call. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-5.3new2/

Comment: actually the call is working despite the notice, and is outputing correctly, {$i->photo()} is a smarty template synthax.